# Adjusting for seasonality doesn't seem to work?

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I am trying to adjust my data (stored as `ts` object in R) for seasonality. I have followed the instructions here [missing link].

```
x <- ts(zero$both.markets, frequency = 7)
ns <- nsdiffs(x) 
if(ns > 0) { xstar <- diff(x, lag=frequency(x), differences=ns) } else { xstar <- x } nd <- ndiffs(xstar) if(nd > 0) { xstar <- diff(xstar,differences=nd) }
```

The probem is that when I check for seasonality again, e.g. by eyeballing it in a plot or by using `decompose`, the data is still very much seasonal.

[image: Seasonality, eh?]

I read in the "Little book of R for time series" that one approach to seasonal data is to decompose the data and the subtract the seasonal component from the original:

```
xstard <- decompose(xstar)
x_sadjusted <- x - xstard$seasonal
```

The problem persists, however, and I don't understand why. I can explain the seasonality, but if I am unable to deal with the problem statistically, can I even use the data in a VAR model?

Edit:

Here is the seasonplot() output.

[image]

Comment: When you say you can "I can explain the seasonality", can you explain what exact seasonal patterns you see.  Eyeballing your graphic looks like random error, but I can't see the time points precisely.

Comment: Are you sure the seasonality is still there? Have you tried plotting your series using function [`seasonplot`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/seasonplot) from "forecast" package in R? Does `auto.arima` select any seasonal lags or does it seasonally difference the series?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy, I added the output. This is after differencing once, using the first piece of code in my post. See here for the original seasonplot: http://imgur.com/dqVuYkA. Underminer yes, the data is weekly and Fri as the lowest point makes theoretical sense. So that this is still the lowest point suggests that there is still seasonality, no?

Comment: First-differencing may not remove seasonality. Have you tried to partial out seasonal dummies using least squares instead?